# Adding class using jQuery in Foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement, foreach

I am running `jQuery` script in `foreach` loop to add classes in html dynamically.I want to add two different classes on different event status but it adds both the class, the class in the `if` condition and class in `else` condition.

Here is my code

```
<?php foreach( $events as $event ){ 
if ($event->status=='new'){ ?>
jQuery( ".upcoming-events" ).addClass( "new_event" );   
<?php } 
else {
?>
jQuery( ".upcoming-events" ).addClass( "old_event" );
<?php } } ?>
```

but it adds both the classes in `upcoming-events` div.

any hint???

Comment: You need to addClass relatively

Comment: you can use hasClass method of jquery to check for class the n remove and add new class

Comment: can you please update $events array here

Comment: That means the `$events` array has at least one new and one old element.

Answer (score 1):

Check my code for your answer

```
<?php foreach( $events as $event ){
if ($event->status=='new'){ ?>
jQuery( ".upcoming-events" ).removeClass( "old_event" );

jQuery( ".upcoming-events" ).addClass( "new_event" );
<?php }
else {
?>
jQuery( ".upcoming-events" ).removeClass( "new_event" );
jQuery( ".upcoming-events" ).addClass( "old_event" );
<?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

".upcoming-events" selector select all elements with upcoming-events class, so if you have any new event you will add new_event class to ALL elements, not only current one.

You must select elements by id, par example.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Mrinmoy's, but here is more simplyfied,

```
<?php 
foreach( $events as $event ){
if ($event->status=='new'){ 
?>
jQuery( ".upcoming-events" ).removeClass( "old_event" ).addClass( "new_event" );
<?php 
} else { 
?>
jQuery( ".upcoming-events" ).removeClass( "new_event" ).addClass( "old_event" );
<?php 
} } 
?>
```